# is selenium grid a solution to my problem with executiontimes?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng, selenium-grid

Hi all I am using TestNG framework for selenium webdriver scripts. I run them on Jenkins on two slaves one being windows the other being linux. I have close to 100 test cases and they take 2hrs 40 mins on each machine. I would want to speed up the execution time.  will selenium grid be helpful in this case?

Answer (score 0):

No. Selenium grid would not be the solution. Selenium grid can multiply the same action, not taking different actions in parallel.

You should look for the opportunities in [test parallelization](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium grid is designed to allow you to run [test in parallel](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/)

The page says:

> Selenium Grid allows us to run tests in parallel on multiple machines, and to manage different browser versions and browser configurations centrally (instead of in each individual test).

However it's not as easy as installing it and connecting up.
You'll need to ensure the rest of your framework and tests are capable of parallel execution. Most important part is to watch out for your test data e.g. if multiple tests rely on the same data source and they try and update it at the same time you'll get flaky results.

You're also capable of running tests in parallel on a local machine without selenium grid.  If i were you i'd start with this first.

Typically most machines have the resources to run more than one browser - get it running locally before you go to far down the grid rabbit hole.

Here's a link for [testng](https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-executing-parallel-tests/)

Also worth a review is [zalenium](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/)  - a docker image that contains a grid  + auto scaling nodes allowing easier browser control on a single machine.